# In which "real-use" cases item.__dict__.iteritems() is used?

Tags: python

Yesterday i was reading some questions here on SO and i came to know `item.__dict__.iteritems()`.
I must admit that i do not know how, when  or why use that, and i also admit it looks beautiful, pythonic.

So, what are some "real-world" uses of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, it has almost no real life use cases aside from introspection. In most cases, `inspect.getmembers` will be better (though it's not a generator: if your classes have enough attributes for that to really be a problem than it's the least of them)

The difference is that `inspect.gemembers` will get both class and instance attributes (and do so all the way up the inheritance chain) whereas only instance attributes live in `instance.__dict__`.

```
>>> class A(object):
...    a = 'a'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
'a'
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> a.b = 'b'
>>> a.__dict__
{'b': 'b'}
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(a)
[('__class__', <class '__main__.A'>), 
 ('__delattr__', <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of A object at 0xb774da8c>),
 ('__dict__', {'b': 'b'}), ('__doc__', None), 
 ('__format__', <built-in method __format__ of A object at 0xb774da8c>),
 # Snipped for brevity
 # ....
 ('__subclasshook__', <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x87b172c>), 
 ('__weakref__', None), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]

>>> list(a.__dict__.iteritems())
[('b', 'b')]
```

In general, `iteritems` is fairly useful anytime you want to look at the key, value entries in a dictionary without expanding them into a list of tuples all at once. It happens to not be incredibly useful when called on *this particular dictionary*.

Comment: I didn't know about `inspect`. :)